# How do I include the same partial multiple times with different content using Nunjucks?

Tags: html, json, nunjucks

I have a few page templates which need to include the same partial numerous times but with different content. I've had a look at looping this, however, they're not necessarily going to be in the concurrent  order.

For example my page template will look like this

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% set page = inner %}

{% block content %}

    {% include "partials/image-text-block.html" %}

    {% include "partials/example-block.html" %}

    {% include "partials/image-text-block.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```

With my include file looking like

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 image-text__copy">
    <h2 class="navy">{{ page.imageText.title }}</h2>

    <p class="light-body">{{ page.imageText.text }}</p>

    <div class="button-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="button">{{ page.imageText.buttonText }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm currently using a json file to inject the content.

```
    "inner": {
        "imageText": {
            "imageSide": "left",
            "text": "dsauhf oaiuoags f"
        }
    }
```

What would be the best way to provide different content to each include please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try using setting different variable values

Input:

```
{% set sectionHeader = { title: 'Title 1', subtitle: 'Subtitle 1' } %}
{% include "_partials/section-header.html" %}

{% set sectionHeader = { title: 'Title 2', subtitle: 'Subtitle 2' } %}
{% include "_partials/section-header.html" %}
```

_partials/section-header.html

```
<header class="section-header">
    <h3 class="section-title">{{sectionHeader.title}}</h3>
    <p class="section-subtitle">{{sectionHeader.subtitle}}</p>
</header>
```

Output:

```
<header class="section-header">
    <h3 class="section-title">Title 1</h3>
    <p class="section-subtitle">Subtitle 1</p>
</header>

<header class="section-header">
    <h3 class="section-title">Title 2</h3>
    <p class="section-subtitle">Subtitle 2</p>
</header>
```

**or you could use macros**

article.njk

```
{% macro articleMacro(title) %}
  <article>
      <header>{{title}}</header>
      <p>article body</p>
      <footer></footer>
  </article>
{% endmacro %}
```

page.njk

```
{% import "article.njk" as article %}

{{ article('header one') }}

{{ article('header two') }}
```

Comment: yes, hierarchical structure processing is only possible in NJK via macros